# Reading and writing I/O tags in a PLC

Tags: python, security, communication, plc, scada

I am reading and writing to I/O tags in `Logix5571` using Python. While dissecting using Wireshark, I could see that the Symbol Class`(0x6b)` is being accessed with Service Codes `0x4c` and `0x4d`. I am confused about the following:

1. Is this the convention in which I/O tags are accessed, as in using the Symbol Class? Is it not Assembly Class? I have read that while doing implicit messaging, Assembly Class is used to access the I/O tags, is it different for the explicit messaging?
2. The services 0x4c and `0x4d` are specific to Symbol Class?
3. How to know what are the instances and attributes present in the Symbol Class?